# URL Rewrite : "http://myServer/" to "http://myServer/sites/site1".?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, wss-3.0

I am trying to use URL Rewrite module on IIS7 to do the following redirection/rewrite (don't know what's better for my case):

I want this URL **"http://myServer/"** to be redirected/rewritten to **"http://myServer/sites/site1"**.

Thanks alot in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

YASH23

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only redirect you'll be doing, the rewrite module is going to be more confusing than necessary if you're not already familiar with it.  I recommend creating a Default site that loads when you go to the root URL (http://myServer/), with the following code in a file named default.asp:

```
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location","http://myServer/sites/site1"
%>
```

That will do a permanent redirect.  If you'd rather do a temporary redirect (so search engines will check there later), do a 302 redirect:

```
<%
Response.Redirect "http://myServer/sites/site1"
Response.End
%>
```

Or, if you'd like to still use IIS URL Rewrite, the regex should just check for an empty string:

```
^$
```

Comment: Michael,
First of all, thanks for the response.. appreciate it..

I wonder why would it be confusing to use the rewrite module in my case, logically it should do what I need.. but none of the pattern regular expressions is working so far..
The redirect solution wouldn't help, since I might need to access the root site ..
Any regex help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @YASH23 - I updated it if you still want to use URL Rewrite.  I just thought if you're not used to doing rewrites, doing a redirect may be easier to manage long term.